# P(A|B) and P(A|C) known, what is P(A|BC)

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Using:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A =1|B=1) &= 0.9\\
P(A =1|C=1) &= 0.9\\
P(A=1) &= 0.5
\end{align}
$$
I want to know the probability of $P(A=1|B=1,C=1)$

I also know that $B$ and $C$ and independent as well as conditionally independent given A.

My approach was to use the following:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A|BC) &= \frac{P(BC|A)P(A)}{P(BC)}\\
&= \frac{P(B|A)P(C|A)P(A)}{P(B)P(C)} &&\qquad \text{using independence}\\
&= \frac{\frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}\frac{P(A|C)P(C)}{P(A)}P(A)}{P(B)P(C)}&&\qquad \text{using Bayes' rule}\\
&=\frac{P(A|B)P(B)P(A|C)P(C)}{P(A)P(B)P(C)}\\
&=\frac{P(A|B)P(A|C)}{P(A)}
\end{align}
$$

Using the known probabilities:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A=1|B=1,C=1) &= \frac{P(A=1|B=1)P(A=1|C=1)}{P(A=1)}\\
&=\frac{0.9*0.9}{0.5}\\
&=1.62
\end{align}
$$

But this is clearly wrong, what step is wrong here?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288770/conditional-probability-given-multiple-independent-events

Comment: @Tim I am using exactly that in the second line, but that gives me this formula.

Comment: Are you sure about your assumptions? It seems correct to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $B$ and $C$ are independent and also conditionally independent given $A$, then your calculation is correct, and the conclusion is valid whenever $P(A)>0$:
$$P(A\mid BC) = \frac{P(A\mid B)P(A\mid C)}{P(A)}.\tag1
$$
Since the LHS of (1) is at most $1$, you can deduce the following constraint:
$$
P(A)\ge P(A\mid B)P(A\mid C),
$$
which is not satisfied by your conditions. So the given assumptions are inconsistent.

Comment: Let's assume $P(B) = 0.0001$ and $P(C) = 0.0001$.  It seems quite possible that $P(A|B) = P(A|C) = 0.9$ while $P(A) = 0.5$ overall.

Comment: @jbowman No matter what $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ are, the OP's assignment of probabilities is not compatible with the additional independence constraints.

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't worked it through in detail.